# Does Self Hosted WCF through Named Pipe use Ports?

Tags: wcf, ipc, self, hosted

Does self hosted wcf through named pipe use ports? But in the below working url it looks like it doesnt.

net.pipe://localhost/TradeService/Service1

All your answers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wcf Net.pipe there is no port concept it uses shared memory..net.pipe only use within system

Comment: Thanks for giving me a clue. You are correct as backed up by this reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733769(v=vs.110).aspx